# Template e Themes para JSF/Primefaces

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, template

Gostaria de tirar uma dúvida e acredito que até seja bem simples. Existem uma grande variedade de templates para AngularJS, WordPress e etc. No site mesmo do Primefaces, tem os themes como por exemplo o Modena, Sentinel, Spark e outros.

Estava pesquisando alguns modelos estilo "Admin Template" e achei alguns em HTML no site ThemeForest com ótimo design. Com isso me surgiu uma dúvida, é possível utilizar algum destes templates e integrar com JSF/Primefaces?

Comment: veja se pode ajudar: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13226_01/workshop/docs92/studio33/JSF/ConvertingHTMLtoJSF.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com JSF em versões mais recentes a resposta é **sim**, mas com alguns poréns. Com PrimeFaces, que é uma especialização do JSF com temas específicos a coisa já fica mais complicada ainda.

Apenas com JSF você pode aproveitar um tema diferente, mas vai ter um grande trabalho para mesclar o tema com as particularidades do JSF.

Já o PrimeFaces vai ser mais complicado ainda porque você precisaria criar um novo tema para o PF, o que não é nada trivial.

O JSF pode ser flexível para aceitar HTML5, mas aí você perde todas aquelas funcionalidades que já viriam prontas para uso.

Se a interface é algo essencial para sua aplicação, sugiro usar outra tecnologia mais flexível, que seja independente do *front end*, como algum framework *action based*.

Se a praticidade for mais importante, sugiro simplesmente usar algum tema padrão do PrimeFaces.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o **HTML(5) Friendly Markup**.

É basicamente a inserção de atributos JSF em tags HTML normais ou de atributos do HTML em tags JSF.

Veja um link com mais detalhes:

> http://blog.triadworks.com.br/suporte-a-html5-com-jsf-2-2

Comment: Aurélio, podes trazer para aqui exemplos e explicação desse link? Como está a resposta fica invompleta. Se o link desaparecer fica inutilizada. Até breve!

Answer (score 1):

> ...é possível utilizar algum destes templates e integrar com
>   JSF/Primefaces?

Sim, dê uma olhada no projeto [AdminFaces](https://github.com/adminfaces) que integra o Primefaces com o bootstrap e o template AdminLTE.

Segue link para o showcase de exemplo: https://adminfaces.github.io/admin-showcase/